# use of ellipses at the end of a paragraph

Tags: punctuation

When a quote ends a paragraph, essentially trailing off, one (generally) uses three ellipses points such as the following:

**"I'm not going to humor that suggestion! There is no way ..."**

Even if the end of the quote completes a sentence, if it's an incomplete thought, it may retain three points

**"I'm not going to humor that suggestion! There is no way I can ..."**

But what about

**Mars, the red planet--but to the Romans, it is the God of War! Herein lies the story [?]**

A period just doesn't seem to cut it. So the question is, three dots or four? And if four, what should the separation be? I realize this is a bit of a style issue. THE CHICAGO MANUAL OF STYLE, which I use, only advocates four equally spaced points if it indicates the removal of paragraph(s) in quoted material.

Comment: Why doesn't a full stop "seem to cut it"?

Comment: True, a period ends a sentence. But I'm introducing a story, and it seems abrupt.

Comment: Never end a sentence with a preposition!  End it by trailing off and ...

Comment: Related question: [Is an ellipsis a distinct punctuation mark?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80948/is-an-ellipsis-a-distinct-punctuation-mark/80965#80965).

Answer (score -1):

> Herein lies the story.

It's a full sentence, so it ends with a period.

(If you insist on using ellipses, use 4; you use 4 to end a full sentence.)

---

Edit: 
The Chicago Manual of Style (13th ed) says:

> 10.47 "In general, no ellipses points should be used 1) before or after an obviously incomplete sentence, 2) before or after a run-in quotation of a complete sentence, 3) before a block quotation beginning with a complete sentence ... 4) after a block quotation ending with a complete sentence."

The OP last sentence in question is "Herein lies the story." This is a complete sentence. It it were a block quotation, by 10.47, point 4, ellipses should not be used.

But the sentence in question is for a narrative passage, not a quoted passage. CMOS uses ellipses for the omission of a word or phrase from within a quoted passage. (10.36) This is not the case, so again, ellipses are contraindicated.

Comment: Please give an example with an answer. Also, may I remind you that this is a professional site, and I am asking for help. Attitude counts. Are you saying __story....__ or __story. ...__ or __story ... .__?

Comment: I like the literal interpretation: "Herein lies the story... ... ... ..." :P

Comment: Hmm, can an elipses be a full sentence on it's own? : - )